# Circular distribution of circles

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

Suppose you have $n$ objects , distributed randomly, in a circular manner of radius $r$. Each objects is of area $A$. So my question is if you draw line everywhere from the center to the surface of the circle, what fraction of all the 360 degrees lines will reach the surface untouched by the objects?

Comment: Are the objects circular?

Comment: Yes, They are circular objects.

Comment: I think your question need more precision. Are the object you distribute identical? What are they? How precisely are they distributed? Can they overlap or are they disjoint? One possibility is to distribute $n$ point $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ uniformly and independtly in the disk of radius one and then consider the small disks of radius $r$ and center $x_i$ (in that case they might overlap for example). Is it what you consider, or you consider an other distribution.

Comment: ok the objects are distinct entities that can't overlap. here is a similar problem, suppose you are in a forest of circular area $A$, In that forest cylinder shaped  trees are distributed randomly , each tree is of an a radius $r$. suppose you are at the center, and light comes to you from every side, modeled in 2-d, what fraction of the light would reach you untouched by the trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Either the objects can't overlap** in this case it's just like putting them side by side. The blue circles have an area $A=\pi a^2 $, $a$ is its radius. The angle $\theta$ verifies $sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{a}{r}$ since the red triangle is isosceles. The probability of having a radius of the green circle not touching any blue circles is :
$$p=\frac{360-n\theta}{360}$$

[image]

**Otherwise the objects can overlap**, in this case each object represents a new trial, each trial being independent. The probability of having a radius of the green circle not touching any blue circles is :
$$p=\left(\frac{360-\theta}{360}\right)^n$$